# Why is a WPF TextBox sending wmiprvse.exe out of control?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, cpu

I have been working on an application, and was trying to figure out why my CPU usage was hitting 80-100%.

I narrowed it down to the TextBox controls in my WPF page. It turns out that if I put focus on them it would start hammering the wmiprvse.exe process. This sent my overall CPU usage up to 100%.

I then created a test WPF application to see whether it may have been underlying code, or whether it is just the TextBox that is the culprit. Turns out, IT IS!

My test form only one text box, but as soon as I put focus on it to start editing some text, my CPU rockets to 100%.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, and do you know of any workaround?

**Update**

Well I have figured it out.

In another application I was using a `ManagementEventWatcher`.  I was querying every second so I may have been creating a backlog somehow.

Here is a little sample of what I removed:

```
private ManagementEventWatcher processCreateWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
processCreateWatcher.Query = new WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", interval, "TargetInstance isa \"Win32_Process\"");
processCreateWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(processCreateWatcher_EventArrived);
processCreateWatcher.Start();
```

Next time I better be careful when using the Management class!

Comment: Works normally for me no CPU rocketing

Comment: I don't have a problem with TexBox and it is a common and widely used control.  I suspect something in your environment that triggered by a TextBox focus.

Comment: Hmmm, I think your right BalamBalam. I just removed some processes from the machine and CPU has remained low. Maybe there are two applications fighting for control over wmiprvse! :/

Comment: Please add your edit as an answer and accept it versus posting the answer in the question.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to do that yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a problem with TexBox and it is a common and widely used control. I suspect something in your environment that is triggered by a TextBox focus.

Answer (score 0):

The `wmiprvse.exe` application is always situated in the Windows operating system’s `systems32` folder. The filename and path is `C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem`. If `wmiprvse.exe` is running from a different origin, meaning outside the `systems32` folder, then there is a huge possibility that it is actually a Trojan or a Virus. Numerous kinds of malware hide under the `wmiprvse.exe` pretext. Users often overlook the possibility of the `wmiprvse.exe` being a malware since it is a common system process, so malware detection may not be detected immediately.

Comment: I am running the application on two separate machines. Both have been rebuilt and have only been running my application. The likelihood of wmiprvse.exe being a virus are pretty slim.

Comment: I hope you don't have a KeyLogger software on your machine, at least the 100%CPU usage in conjuntion with a TextBox Focus sounds very very suspicious to me ... :(

Comment: I had an application looking at processes that are being created or stopped, which is kind of similar I suppose. Must have been performing my WMI query too many times.

Answer (score 0):

`wmiprvse.exe` is the Windows Management Instrumentation Provider Service. Normally you would not expect that there would be any connection between a text box and the CPU load of the WMI provider service. However, WMI can be extended with custom providers and these providers will run inside `wmiprvse.exe`. You may have a buggy provider installed on your system.